# Automatic updates on Android devices (Apps) - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play

When I publish a new version in google play, why is not updated automatically in the final devices? even though the option of automatic update in the devices is activated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be updated automatically in devices with automatic updates, but not immediately. Some things that you might not expect:

- Devices only checkin to Play about once a day for updates, then do all their updates together, instead of getting a push notification to update when a new version of an app comes out. If the  push notification happened, imagine what would happen when YouTube pushes an update. Immediately 2 billion devices would all hit Google Play servers at the same time. This would be like a DoS attack on Google Play. Because different devices check in at different points over 24 hours, the load is spread.
- By default devices only update when connected to WiFi and plugged into a power supply. Plugged into WiFi is the option because data can be very expensive for some users. If users want to update on mobile data they can change the setting. Power is because some update operations can use a lot  of CPU. Downloading uses the network circuits and decompression and patching can be quite CPU intensive. By waiting until the device is plugged in, Google Play doesn't suddenly drain the battery of a user who is hoping it will last until they get home.

But you should see automatic updates for most users within a day or two of publishing your update. Some users itwill take a lot longer because they have disabled automatic updates or rarely have WiFi and Power at the same time.